# Java handling packets with objects

Tags: java, oop

I am communicating with a server. Lot of packets, parsing some of theese can be very long, so i am looking for good way how to do it in some handling files.
I can do something like

```
main:
...
switch(packet[0])
    case "recv_g":
    //some stuff
    break;
```

but i would like to do it like this:

```
main:
...
Handle(packet);

recv_gHandler.java:
class..
//do some stuff
```

In Handle should not be the switch between handlers. How can i do this? I hope you understand :)

Comment: You should be sending an opcode and a packet size (for verification, if necessary).  Sending information in a `String` will be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: I have packet in string how it comes from server (before i decrypt it). It could has some parameters and it could look like "packet 0 0 0 5 0 0 0".

Comment: Like I said, it's not a good idea to send a `String` over a network unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The server isnt mine, i am just communicating with him/it.

Comment: I fail to understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to select a Handler object based on a String value, without using a switch? If not, what are you asking?

Comment: Yes. I have several files xxxHandler and i want to somehow push the packet in string into the handler without using switch. I think i can call every handler and into handler put if(packet[0]!="...") return but thats not nice solution for me

Comment: Create a Map<String, Handler>, and get the appropriate handler from the map. That is a little bit more elegant than a switch, but a switch basically does the same thing.

Comment: I will put handler objects into an array then foreach it. Thanks you.

Comment: So you ask a question, but disregard the answer and instead use something else, that was never suggested. Why did you ask a question?

Comment: If it sounded like sarcasm sorry, i will use it like this, its better then switch. Just initialize all that handlers and adding them into array. But still i need to write every name of that handler so its not perfect.

Comment: Again, don't use an array. Use a Map<String, Handler>.